# How do I get the save results from a JayData saveChanges() call?

Tags: jaydata

In JayData, how do I find out how my saveChanges() call went?  In Breeze, the save command returns a saveResults object.  Is there anything equivalent in JayData?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer: I work for the JayData project

Unfortunately individual results of the batch operation are not accessible in the current version when using `context.saveChanges()`. In general you'll be able to receive the status of the results through the `then() and fail()` branches promise handlers (jQuery required).

You'll have more detailed info about the exception result (error details) if you are using the instance `save()`, `remove()` etc methods as you'll get detailed error response in the fail() branch.

If the result contains entity updates then those updates are automatically merged into the live entity instance - both with `saveChanges()` and `instance.save()`.

If you need to process the protocol result use `context.prepareRequest()` to intercept the http communication.